# should i use both google analytics 4(GA4) and universal analytics(UA)

Tags: universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am trying to make use of google analytics, but it has two different IDs - UA and GA4.
Should i use both or one of them is sufficient.
if it is just one of them then which one should i make use for my nuxt project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to choose only one of them.

If you use the GA Nuxt library called [nuxt/google-analytics](https://google-analytics.nuxtjs.org/) you will have to use the Universal Analytics (UA) since the library only supports it.

However, you can definitely use GA4 with the id pattern `G-XXXXXXXX` by creating an `app.html` file in the [root of your project](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/views/#document-apphtml) and pasting the GA4 `<script>` tag in there. You should end up with something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    {{ HEAD }}
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

I guess it's your choice to use whatever you want, both would work very well!